# Data distribution for a system with SOA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sinatra, soa

I have a **rails** application which manages different types of items and users who own them. Items of different types might have different *features*. There is a number of **sinatra** services which have to access items (**read-only**, every service one specific item type).

Is it a good idea to create separate tables / databases for every service and to keep them in sync with the rails DB? In this case the main DB will hold all items. It's postgres, so hstore could be used for different features. On all updates a sync message will be sent using Redis pub/sub or RabbitMQ messaging. Services will subscribe and update service specific tables.

The system should be really reliable, scalable, and prepared for high-load and new not yet known item categories. What do you think? Does it make sense or are there better approaches for these requirements? Thank you in advance, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer here.  The answer depends on your requirements and these will decide which of two approaches you might take.

The first approach is conceptually the simplest, which is to have every service hit the same database.  The advantage here is that you can scale up relatively easily, the system is simple and flexible, and you can do a lot with the database to keep things working well.  The disadvantage is that db downtime will take down all services at once.

The second approach is to keep every service (or group of closely related services) as separate self-contained service, kept in sync with some sort of message passing.  This has the advantage of being more robust in terms of delivering basic services, but far less robust in terms of everything staying in sync (because the CAP theorem's consistency requirement is sacrificed for availability, and your data is effectively partitioned).

I don't know which one you will want to use.  To the extent possible I would usually choose the single db approach but I am a Postgres guy, not a Rails guy.  The second approach also works quite well in some cases but it does have a complexity cost.